# Not all items listed in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I can see that not all items show up in my admin. I can open them using `id` in url, but they are not listed so I can't search and filter them. What could be wrong?

There's also `1735 results` and `2519 total` in list footer and header.

Here's how my `admin.py` looks like:

```
class DetalAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Detal
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs.get('instance', None):
            if not kwargs.get('initial', None):
                kwargs['initial'] = {}
            if not kwargs['initial'].get('number', None):
                kwargs['initial']['number'] = get_first_unused_detal_number()
        super(DetalAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class CellListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Ячейка (включая доп. места)'
    parameter_name = 'cell_number'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        cells_list = StoringCell.objects.all().values_list('id', 'number')
        return cells_list

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        cell_number = self.value()
        return queryset.filter(Q(cell__id=cell_number) | Q(dopolnenie__cell__id=cell_number)).distinct()

class DetalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DetalAdminForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields' : ['number']}),
        ('...', {'fields' : ['name', 'tipe', 'korpus', 'primechanie', ('cell', 'kol_nalicie', 'upakovka')]}),
        )
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_display = ('number', 'tipe', 'name', 'korpus', 'cell', 'kol_nalicie', 'get_adds_amount')
    list_display_links = ['number', 'tipe', 'name', 'korpus', 'cell', 'kol_nalicie']
    list_filter = ['da_net', 'tipe', 'korpus', 'cell', CellListFilter]
    list_select_related = True
    ordering = ['number']
    inlines = [DopolnenieInline, OpisanieInline, KodPostavInline]
```

I did some schema and data migrations some time ago, maybe I did something wrong? And if I did something wrong why I can still access the objects?

Comment: Usually, question like this is to localized, but I used to have a similar case. The issue I have is that I manually manipulated the id of instance. Generally, when you add a new instance to your db, db will give a default id for it. However, for some reason, I have to create some instances with specified id (id is large enough to make sure there is not and will be not collisions). In that case, django will give the total with count(), and show the instances with default assigned ID. Maybe not your case, but not bad think about it at least

Comment: It would be great to know how Django distinguishes ids that were assigned manually... Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: what is in your admin.py file?

Comment: @elmonkeylp I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with custom filter CellListFilter. I should have checked if the `parameter_name` was in the `request.GET`:

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.parameter_name in request.GET:
            cell_number = self.value()
            return queryset.filter(Q(cell__id=cell_number) | Q(dopolnenie__cell__id=cell_number)).distinct()
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [list_max_show_all](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_max_show_all) and [list_per_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page) in your admin.py

like

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_max_show_all = 3000
    list_per_page = 500
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.